# Keeping part of money collected as donation as service charge

Tags: zakat, sadaqah

I am planning to raise undertake an orphan/poor education project where I will school these kids. Obviously the money required to do so will come from donation. My question is quite simple. Considering the plan that I have I will need to provide my full time effort in raising funds as well as managing the entire execution. I currently have a full-time job, Alhamdulillah. Is it permissible if I keep a part of the money that comes from donation as my salary for the time that I spend.

Please advise.

Comment: Obviously the donaters will look into your advertisement (maybe your pamphlets),  can't you mention 'I will use some of this money for my sustenance' ? If this is done then there is nothing wrong

Comment: Depending upon which country this is, there may be legal requirements that define what you are allowed to do and what you must disclose.  I'd start by determining this information first, and *then* asking about any additional religious aspects within that context.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. Based on the following verse:

> Test orphans until they reach marriageable age; then, if you find they have sound judgement, hand over their property to them. Do not consume it hastily before they come of age: **if the guardian is well off he should abstain from the orphan’s property**, and **if he is poor he should use only what is fair**. When you give them their property, call witnesses in; but God takes full account of everything you do.

If the school will run on donations to the orphans, those donations would count as the orphan's property. If you already have enough wealth and are well off even without your job, you should not take any money. If you do need the money to feed yourself and your family because you will be poor without the job, you should take only a fair amount.

Either way, I suggest that you follow Allah's advice and include neutral witnesses in the whole process, so as to deter yourself from overreaching and to prevent anyone else from slandering you.

Answer (score 0):

If the donations are zakat due then some say the maximum you can be retained as collectors is 1/8 of the proceeds some says you are not allowed unless an Islamic authority permits you to do so.

If the donations are from non-obligatory dues then there will be no restriction, however, any case you must disclose this information to the donor

Comment: Who are these "some" who say so, please don't confound Islam Stack Exchange with a typical internet forum. We are looking for well elaborated answers focused on answering the actual question and claims to be supported by evidences.